# How to convert time from seconds from 1970 to real time in Python plot?

Tags: python, plot, cluster-computing, k-means

I am using K means algorithm to compute the number of clusters needed for my data and also to display the result in a scatter plot. The problem is that, for this algorithm, i need to use the dates as codes, like 1572559240. After computing the clusters, how can I plot the date values like 01/11/2019 instead of the code? This is the snippet for plotting.

```
X = df.iloc[:, [0, 8]].values  # time code and ch2o values

cluster_figure.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=X[y_kmeans == 1, 0], y=X[y_kmeans == 1, 1], mode='markers',
                                    marker=dict(color='blue'), name='Cluster 2'))

cluster_figure.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=X[y_kmeans == 2, 0], y=X[y_kmeans == 2, 1], mode='markers',
                                    marker=dict(color='green'), name='Cluster 3'))
cluster_figure.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], y=kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1], mode='markers',
                                    marker=dict(color='yellow'), name='Centroids'))
```

Here is the link to the full code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zd22Pz-rjvDsmAtE5b5J8gE9DJysAo9v

Answer (score 0):

The datetime module can handle it -

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = 1576748381
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

You could now format that with the datetime to string converter (eg `date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` . You can add a column to your df with dates in that format along the lines of

```
df['date']=df.apply(lambda r:datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(r[0]).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'),axis=1)
```

and then use those for x values instead of the epoch times, eg

```
cluster_figure.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=X[y_kmeans == 1, 9], y=X[y_kmeans == 1, 1], mode='markers',                                    marker=dict(color='blue'), name='Cluster 2'))
```

assuming the date columns wound up being column #9; from your definition of X it looks like columns 0-8 are filled.

Comment: I know how to convert the date normally, I don't know how to convert it and to show it in the kmeans plot...